# Convert a date (in UTC) to date in another timezone (with support for DST)

Tags: javascript, date, react-native, timezone, momentjs

**Problem Statement** - I need to convert a UTC formatted date to a date in another timezone. The other timezone may or may not support DST.

**Data Available to me**:

1. The Windows Timezone ID (ex. Pacific Standard Time)
2. The UTC Offset for that timezone
3. Whether the timezone supports DST (Daylight Savings)
4. The DST UTC offset

Using the above data I am able to convert the time to the required timezone, but how do I check whether DST is currently active for that timezone? If I get to know that DST is active then I can use the DST offset and not the standard offset.

**Technology** - JavaScript, React-Native (I am open to using moment.js if needed).

Comment: Do you need to keep in mind DST at all? Use UTC offset and you will be okay unless you are operating with durations or kind of time periods measured in units smaller than days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`momentjs` has a [isDST](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/) method that can be used in combination with [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```js
//see https://gist.github.com/danderson00/c03d46dfc38486ea7b06da9f75c7a63f
let windowsToIANA = {
  "Dateline Standard Time": "Etc/GMT+12",
  "UTC-11": "Etc/GMT+11",
  "Aleutian Standard Time": "America/Adak",
  "Hawaiian Standard Time": "Pacific/Honolulu",
  "Marquesas Standard Time": "Pacific/Marquesas",
  "Alaskan Standard Time": "America/Anchorage",
  "UTC-09": "Etc/GMT+9",
  "Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)": "America/Tijuana",
  "UTC-08": "Etc/GMT+8",
  "Pacific Standard Time": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "US Mountain Standard Time": "America/Phoenix",
  "Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)": "America/Chihuahua",
  "Mountain Standard Time": "America/Denver",
  "Central America Standard Time": "America/Guatemala",
  "Central Standard Time": "America/Chicago",
  "Easter Island Standard Time": "Pacific/Easter",
  "Central Standard Time (Mexico)": "America/Mexico_City",
  "Canada Central Standard Time": "America/Regina",
  "SA Pacific Standard Time": "America/Bogota",
  "Eastern Standard Time (Mexico)": "America/Cancun",
  "Eastern Standard Time": "America/New_York",
  "Haiti Standard Time": "America/Port-au-Prince",
  "Cuba Standard Time": "America/Havana",
  "US Eastern Standard Time": "America/Indianapolis",
  "Paraguay Standard Time": "America/Asuncion",
  "Atlantic Standard Time": "America/Halifax",
  "Venezuela Standard Time": "America/Caracas",
  "Central Brazilian Standard Time": "America/Cuiaba",
  "SA Western Standard Time": "America/La_Paz",
  "Pacific SA Standard Time": "America/Santiago",
  "Turks And Caicos Standard Time": "America/Grand_Turk",
  "Newfoundland Standard Time": "America/St_Johns",
  "Tocantins Standard Time": "America/Araguaina",
  "E. South America Standard Time": "America/Sao_Paulo",
  "SA Eastern Standard Time": "America/Cayenne",
  "Argentina Standard Time": "America/Buenos_Aires",
  "Greenland Standard Time": "America/Godthab",
  "Montevideo Standard Time": "America/Montevideo",
  "Magallanes Standard Time": "America/Punta_Arenas",
  "Saint Pierre Standard Time": "America/Miquelon",
  "Bahia Standard Time": "America/Bahia",
  "UTC-02": "Etc/GMT+2",
  "Azores Standard Time": "Atlantic/Azores",
  "Cape Verde Standard Time": "Atlantic/Cape_Verde",
  "UTC": "Etc/GMT",
  "Morocco Standard Time": "Africa/Casablanca",
  "GMT Standard Time": "Europe/London",
  "Greenwich Standard Time": "Atlantic/Reykjavik",
  "W. Europe Standard Time": "Europe/Berlin",
  "Central Europe Standard Time": "Europe/Budapest",
  "Romance Standard Time": "Europe/Paris",
  "Central European Standard Time": "Europe/Warsaw",
  "W. Central Africa Standard Time": "Africa/Lagos",
  "Jordan Standard Time": "Asia/Amman",
  "GTB Standard Time": "Europe/Bucharest",
  "Middle East Standard Time": "Asia/Beirut",
  "Egypt Standard Time": "Africa/Cairo",
  "E. Europe Standard Time": "Europe/Chisinau",
  "Syria Standard Time": "Asia/Damascus",
  "West Bank Standard Time": "Asia/Hebron",
  "South Africa Standard Time": "Africa/Johannesburg",
  "FLE Standard Time": "Europe/Kiev",
  "Israel Standard Time": "Asia/Jerusalem",
  "Kaliningrad Standard Time": "Europe/Kaliningrad",
  "Sudan Standard Time": "Africa/Khartoum",
  "Libya Standard Time": "Africa/Tripoli",
  "Namibia Standard Time": "Africa/Windhoek",
  "Arabic Standard Time": "Asia/Baghdad",
  "Turkey Standard Time": "Europe/Istanbul",
  "Arab Standard Time": "Asia/Riyadh",
  "Belarus Standard Time": "Europe/Minsk",
  "Russian Standard Time": "Europe/Moscow",
  "E. Africa Standard Time": "Africa/Nairobi",
  "Iran Standard Time": "Asia/Tehran",
  "Arabian Standard Time": "Asia/Dubai",
  "Astrakhan Standard Time": "Europe/Astrakhan",
  "Azerbaijan Standard Time": "Asia/Baku",
  "Russia Time Zone 3": "Europe/Samara",
  "Mauritius Standard Time": "Indian/Mauritius",
  "Saratov Standard Time": "Europe/Saratov",
  "Georgian Standard Time": "Asia/Tbilisi",
  "Caucasus Standard Time": "Asia/Yerevan",
  "Afghanistan Standard Time": "Asia/Kabul",
  "West Asia Standard Time": "Asia/Tashkent",
  "Ekaterinburg Standard Time": "Asia/Yekaterinburg",
  "Pakistan Standard Time": "Asia/Karachi",
  "India Standard Time": "Asia/Calcutta",
  "Sri Lanka Standard Time": "Asia/Colombo",
  "Nepal Standard Time": "Asia/Katmandu",
  "Central Asia Standard Time": "Asia/Almaty",
  "Bangladesh Standard Time": "Asia/Dhaka",
  "Omsk Standard Time": "Asia/Omsk",
  "Myanmar Standard Time": "Asia/Rangoon",
  "SE Asia Standard Time": "Asia/Bangkok",
  "Altai Standard Time": "Asia/Barnaul",
  "W. Mongolia Standard Time": "Asia/Hovd",
  "North Asia Standard Time": "Asia/Krasnoyarsk",
  "N. Central Asia Standard Time": "Asia/Novosibirsk",
  "Tomsk Standard Time": "Asia/Tomsk",
  "China Standard Time": "Asia/Shanghai",
  "North Asia East Standard Time": "Asia/Irkutsk",
  "Singapore Standard Time": "Asia/Singapore",
  "W. Australia Standard Time": "Australia/Perth",
  "Taipei Standard Time": "Asia/Taipei",
  "Ulaanbaatar Standard Time": "Asia/Ulaanbaatar",
  "Aus Central W. Standard Time": "Australia/Eucla",
  "Transbaikal Standard Time": "Asia/Chita",
  "Tokyo Standard Time": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "North Korea Standard Time": "Asia/Pyongyang",
  "Korea Standard Time": "Asia/Seoul",
  "Yakutsk Standard Time": "Asia/Yakutsk",
  "Cen. Australia Standard Time": "Australia/Adelaide",
  "AUS Central Standard Time": "Australia/Darwin",
  "E. Australia Standard Time": "Australia/Brisbane",
  "AUS Eastern Standard Time": "Australia/Sydney",
  "West Pacific Standard Time": "Pacific/Port_Moresby",
  "Tasmania Standard Time": "Australia/Hobart",
  "Vladivostok Standard Time": "Asia/Vladivostok",
  "Lord Howe Standard Time": "Australia/Lord_Howe",
  "Bougainville Standard Time": "Pacific/Bougainville",
  "Russia Time Zone 10": "Asia/Srednekolymsk",
  "Magadan Standard Time": "Asia/Magadan",
  "Norfolk Standard Time": "Pacific/Norfolk",
  "Sakhalin Standard Time": "Asia/Sakhalin",
  "Central Pacific Standard Time": "Pacific/Guadalcanal",
  "Russia Time Zone 11": "Asia/Kamchatka",
  "New Zealand Standard Time": "Pacific/Auckland",
  "UTC+12": "Etc/GMT-12",
  "Fiji Standard Time": "Pacific/Fiji",
  "Chatham Islands Standard Time": "Pacific/Chatham",
  "UTC+13": "Etc/GMT-13",
  "Tonga Standard Time": "Pacific/Tongatapu",
  "Samoa Standard Time": "Pacific/Apia",
  "Line Islands Standard Time": "Pacific/Kiritimati"
} 
//create link
Object.entries(windowsToIANA).forEach(([win, IANA]) => {
   moment.tz.link(`${IANA}|${win}`);
})

var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-01-01 12:00", "Eastern Standard Time");
var london = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "GMT Standard Time");
console.log(newYork.format('ha z'))
console.log(newYork.isDST())
console.log(london.format('ha z'))
console.log(london.isDST())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: moment.js doesn't use Windows Timezone ID (it is using IANA)

Comment: @PratikBhattacharya I've updated the example using a map between Windows Timezone ID to IANA and push this to the `link` method. So you can use the Windows Timezone ID.

Comment: Where an implementation supports the *timeZone* option of *toLocaleString*, then the conversion to IANA timezone is all that's required, e.g. `new Date().toLocaleString('en-au',{timeZone:'Pacific/Norfolk'})`. However, formatting with moment.js is likely easier.

Comment: @VictorPerez, http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml is this your source?

Comment: @PratikBhattacharya Yes, but I used https://gist.github.com/danderson00/c03d46dfc38486ea7b06da9f75c7a63f
what is using http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml You can also create your own mapping between Windows Zones ID and IANA zones using this XML if you want